# what is Dynamic Linq query

Tags: linq

i never work with DLINQ so i dont know the use of DLINQ. so can anyone show the situation where DLINQ is required and also show me the various  use of DLINQ.

Comment: DLINQ transformed into Linq2Sql. DLINQ is dead.

Comment: @Mitch: How did DLINQ transform? I though they just changed the name of everything from "xLINQ" to "Linq2x".

Comment: @Gabe: whatever. The point is DLINQ no longer exists as DLINQ. The poster is asking about a term that has not been used for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"While writing type-safe queries is great for most scenarios, there are cases where you want the flexibility to dynamically construct queries on the fly.  For example: you might want to provide business intelligence UI within your application that allows an end-user business analyst to use drop-downs to build and express their own custom queries/views on top of data. "
from: [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)